# How do I remove the negative sign from this derivation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, atomic-physics

A homework problem required me to show that the first equation below can be written in the form of the second equation. It was all fairly simple except for the negative sign. I'm not sure how this is supposed to cancel out. Might there be some conceptual way that the negative sign is removed?

**1st Equation:**
$$E_n=-\frac{mk^2Z^2e^4}{2 \hbar^2 n^2}$$

**2nd Equation:**
$$E_1=\frac{\alpha^2 mc^2}{2}$$

**All I did was to substitute this and simplify:**

$$\alpha=\frac{ke^2}{\hbar c}$$

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Unfortunately, the problem does not have that negative sign. If it did, this would have been easy :/

Comment: Have you ever encountered imaginary numbers?  Go research that idea.

Comment: @BillN the 2nd equation doesn't have an $i$ though

Comment: Put $i$ in your $\alpha$, then $\alpha^2$ will have a negative sign with it to match the first equation.

Comment: @BillN but how is that allowed? To me (a novice, admittedly) that seems illegal because I wouldn't also be putting an $i$ in the denominator.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel: Recall that $(-x)\cdot(-x)=+x^2$ ;)

Answer (score 1):

There should be a negative sign in Equation 2.  The exercise is a very simple  one in substitution and does not require any sign cancelling.

Comment: Right, I totally agree with you. I did manage to find another error in this book on a different problem and promptly told my professor, but since this one is so simple I thought there may have been a concept I missed that would lead me to the given conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

In the first equation you can replace the minus sign ($-$) by $i^2$, then factor that to be part of the $\alpha$.

Comment: Hm...Well this seems legit. I'll ask my professor once I get my homework back (I turned this in a while ago). I want to see what he thinks of this. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: I can't imagine any situation in which it would be useful to have an imaginary fine structure constant. Most likely someone didn't want to bother writing all the signs.

Comment: @Javier  I agree. And that goes to strongly infer that there is a sign error in one of the equations. I, however, was simply proposing a mathematically valid alternative explanation which would be reasonable without identifying $\alpha$ as the fine structure constant.

Comment: @BillN: Your alternative is mathematically valid but not physically valid, since $\alpha$ *is* the fine structure constant (at least in this context).